# vowpal wabbit installation encounters error of `rapidjson/reader.h'

Tags: vowpalwabbit

I have problems when installing vowpal wabbit in my ubuntu-14.04 machine.

Based on the guide of https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit, everything works fine until I input `make’. The error shows that`fatal error: rapidjson/reader.h: No such file or directory’.

I check the path of `./vowpal_wabbit/vowpalwabbit/rapidjson’ and find that it only contains`reader.md’.

How should I debug this case? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Did you do anything before typing `make`?  On Ubuntu, a simple build using `make` should work out of the box. There's no need for automake/autogen/configure.  The only thing you need is to make sure you have all prerequisites installed first via `apt-get install ...`.  On https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit scroll down to the *Ubuntu/Debian specific info* section and follow the instructions in that section.  If you get an error on a clean clone, you should report it as a bug/issue on github.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I just solved this problem, go following my steps:

1.`git clone git://github.com/miloyip/rapidjson`

2.go to the folder you just downloaded, find the folder `./include` and put the folder `rapidjson` in the /usr/include/

3.try to `make` again.

Comment: Have you run into any issues with vowpal not working as expected? I think the directory structure was intended to be like that..

Answer (score 0):

I received:

```
$ git clone git://github.com/miloyip/rapidjson    
Cloning into 'rapidjson'...    
fatal: remote error: 
  The unauthenticated git protocol on port 9418 is no longer supported.    
Please see https://github.blog/2021-09-01-improving-git-protocol-security-github/ for more information.
```

I have solved using either:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/Tencent/rapidjson.git
```

or

```
$ git clone https://github.com/miloyip/rapidjson.git
```

Then, since /usr/include doesn't exist in MacOS, I copied the folder in `/usr/local/include/`:

```
$ sudo cp -r rapidjson/include/rapidjson /usr/local/include/
```